# can't evaluate field data in type string

Tags: html, templates, go

trying to print the content for the variable data into an html page:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "html/template"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init(){
    tpl= template.Must(template.ParseGlob("*.html"))
}

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/",  index)
    http.HandleFunc("/process", processor)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html",nil)
}

func processor(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Redirect(w,r,"/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }
    data := r.FormValue("data")
    fmt.Printf("%s",data)
    err:=tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "processor.html", string(data))
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("execution failed: %s", err)
}
    //tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "processor.html",data)
}
```

here's the html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PROCESSOR</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{.data}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is what my shell prints:

```
poo2020/03/22 19:13:50 execution failed: template: processor.html:8:11: executing "processor.html" at <.data>: can't evaluate field data in type string
exit status 1
```

poo being the content of data (proof that i'm getting it from the initial html page correctly.
checked some similar issues, tried to use a variable $data, but i get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string variable to template processor, so that's all there's in its context, so you have to use:

```
{{.}}
```

in the template to print it. Or, you can pass the context with a "data" field as:

```
 err:=tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "processor.html", map[string]interface{}{"data":string(data)})
```

and use

```
{{.data}}
```

in the template.

Whatever object you pass into the `ExecuteTemplate` is accessible using `{{.}}`. The notation `{{.data}}` will access a field name `data` in that object.